# How do I gain access to the files within the resources directory in my Maven web service project?

Tags: java, maven

My Maven web service project has this basic structure:

```
MyWebService\
|-- src\
|   |-- main\
|   |   |-- java\
|   |   `-- resources\
|   |       `-- csvfiles\
|   |           `-- data.csv
|   `-- test\
`-- target\
    |-- classes\
    `-- test-classes\
```

I am trying to access the .csv files in the `csvfiles` subdirectory of my `resources` subdirectory.

I have a class with this code:

```
public class ReadCSVFiles {
    public void read(){
        String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        ClassLoader cl = ReadCSVFiles.class.getClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.getResource(separator + "src" + separator + "main" + separator + "resources" + separator + "csvfiles" + "data.csv");
        url.toString();
    }
}
```

The path ends up being:

```
\src\main\resources\csvfiles\data.csv
```

I also tried this path:

```
src\main\resources\csvfiles\data.csv
```

Whenever I run my application, I always get a `NullPointerException` on the `url.toString()` line.

So, how do I go about getting access to those .csv data files?

Comment: @Jeyaprakash I'm not sure what you mean. I ran this exact  code with both paths and got the NPE both times.

Comment: No directory named `src/main/resources` ends up in the jar/war. That directory name is just Maven convention for where to put files that need to end up in an artifact, but don't require compilation etc. I suggest running `jar tvf <myArtifact>` to print out the names of the files in the jar, locate the data.csv file, and write code to read that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the classloader to get a resource in the classpath (resources folder), just use the relative path:

`ReadCSVFiles.class.getClassLoader().getResource("csvfiles/data.csv");`

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure why do you want to print the URL here, the classLoader.getResource has taken your resource directory as the root here. If you want to read the CSV and do some action on that that file then directly read the file using an InputStream.

Like the below

```
public class ReadCSVFiles {
public void read(){
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    ClassLoader cl = ReadCSVFiles.class.getClassLoader();
     try (InputStream inputStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("csvfiles/data.csv")) {

        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
       for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
          // Process line
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Or if you need to get the URL and then load the file through the URL you can try something like below

```
URL url = cl.getResource("csvfiles/data.csv");
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I was just trying to trigger (or not trigger) the NPE for test purposes.